# Redundant hash join in SQL developer's autotrace execution plan?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

Total newbie in SQL developer, I'm using the autotrace to understand the execution plan.
In this autotrace output, what's the purpose of the last hash join?

[image: autotrace output]

Suppose the second ("the upper one") nested loop join can already be the final view as all the attributes are there and predicate conditions are met?

**SQL:**

```
SELECT TITLE, LASTNAME 
FROM MOVIE2 M, ARTIST A 
WHERE CODECOUNTRY='aaej' AND M.IDMES=A.IDARTIST;
```

Comment: Please learn e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) how you can post the execution plan *in text form* (not image) and *complete* (with predicate information).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the new feature of Oracle 12g  **Adaptive Joins**

e.g. [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/whats-new-in-12c:-adaptive-joins) (blog) or [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-optimizer-with-oracledb-12c-1963236.pdf) (white paper) or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optcncpt.htm#TGSQL221) (documentation)

Oracle will perform either `NESTED LOOPS` if there are small number of rows to be joined,

or will fall back to a  `HASH  JOIN` if there are a large number of rows, because the `NESTED LOOP` will take too long time to finish in this case.

The important line in the plan is `STATISTICS COLLECTOR` that observes the threshold of the row count and triggers the plan change if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! I've now run the execution plan in text form as you've suggested.
I notice there's only a `hash join` executed. So, for the 2 `nested loop joins` seen in autotrace, they are not executed after `statistics collector` ran the analysis?

Even so, I don't get why there are 2 `nested loop joins` in the autotrace; suppose if the collector needs to compare between `hash` & `nested loop joins`, there should still only be 1 (instead of 2) nested loop shown in autotrace?